# Exclusion in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am a novice to SQL.  So I will try to explain my situation as simply as possible.

Say I have two tables named main and mainstage.  They both contain many fields, but they both have a field named uniqueID.

**main Table**

- uniqueID
- 1
- 2
- 3

**mainstage Table**

- uniqueID
- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5
- 6

I need to select all the records from mainstage based on a date range on a field called modifiedDT that do not have a uniqueID in common with the main table, so I need to select all records from mainstage based on a date range but exclude records 1,2, and 3.  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately there are no dates here. The problem is insoluble

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a simple nested query with NOT IN clause -

```
SELECT * FROM mainstage
WHERE uniqueID NOT IN (
    SELECT uniqueID FROM main
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rishikesh!  I left out on other very imprtant detail.  The query to get the records from mainstage will be based upon a date range for a field labeled modifiedDT.  What the two tables have in common is the uniqueID.  So I don't think this will work as is.  I'm going to modify the question to reflect this.

Comment: sure, you can use AND when you have more than one condition in WHERE clause. So add your date range condition after an AND :)

Comment: I should probably put the date range first to get the records I actually want from mainstage, right?  so something like ... WHERE (daterange) AND uniqueID NOT IN ...

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's first or last. The result will be same